# JavaScript Cross site scripting - Settings in Firefox browser

Tags: xss

In Internet Explorer 6, there is a setting to add the domains to trustred sites to overcome cross site scripting.

Is there any such setting available in Firefox browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. I think the answer is no, at least not as a setting that is as simple as the "trusted sites" dialog. What do you want this for?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for this setting to allow cross site scripting for both IE and Firefox browser for internal parent domains.IE allows cross site scripting if domains are added to trusted sites, but I think Firefox does not have such setting.